# removing text before and after ()

Tags: sed, awk, grep

How do I remove the text till the first ( and after )?

```
INSERT INTO `todel` VALUES (1,'akbar\'s','Mumbai, Delhi road, India');
INSERT INTO `todel` VALUES (2,'amar\"s','South Africa, ghana');
```

The expected output is like this...

```
1,'akbar\'s','Mumbai, Delhi road, India'
2,'amar\"s','South Africa, ghana'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ruby(1.9+)

```
$> ruby -ne 'print $_.sub(/.*\(|\).*$/,"")' file
1,'akbar\'s','Mumbai, Delhi road, India'
2,'amar\"s','South Africa, ghana'
```

or the shell(bash)

```
$> while read -r line; do line=${line#*(}; echo ${line%)*}; done <file
1,'akbar\'s','Mumbai, Delhi road, India'
2,'amar\"s','South Africa, ghana'
```

or awk

```
$> awk '{sub(/.*\(/,"");sub(/\).*/,"")}1' file
1,'akbar\'s','Mumbai, Delhi road, India'
2,'amar\"s','South Africa, ghana'
```

or sed

```
$> sed -rn 's/.*\(//;s/\).*//p' file
1,'akbar\'s','Mumbai, Delhi road, India'
2,'amar\"s','South Africa, ghana'
```

Answer (score 1):

awk can take a regular expression as field separator, so use either parenthesis as the field separator and just emit the 2nd field:

```
awk -F'[()]' '{print $2}' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove everything from beginning of line until the first `(` and from (including) the last `)` till the end of line with `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/^[^(]*\(.*)\)[^)]*$/\1/'
```